# Compactness and Convergence of Subsequences

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(X,\rho)$ be a metric space. Suppose that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb Z_+}$ is such a sequence in $X$ that any subsequence has a further subsequence that is convergent. However, the limits of these sub-subsequences are *not* necessarily the same.

Let $A$ be the image set of the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb Z_+}$ (that is, the elements of the sequence viewed as a set, after suppressing repetitions). My question is: Without further assumptions (chiefly, completeness of $(X,\rho)$), $\textbf{is it true that the closure of } A \textbf{ is compact?}$

If so, how can I prove it? My intuition suggests it is, since I think the convergence of the sub-subsequences imposes a bound on both $A$ and its accumulation points, but I cannot seem to formalize this intuition.

Comment: Pick $x_n = 1/n \in X = \mathbb R$. This set is not compact. Do you  also assume that the limit is in $A$?

Comment: @John I'm looking at the _closure_ of $A$. In your example, this is just $\{1/n\,|\,n\in\mathbb Z_+\}\cup\{0\}$, which is compact.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that.^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can show that $\bar A$ is compact by showing that it is sequentially compact.

Let $\{y_n\}\in \bar A$ be any sequence. We can assume that

$$\{ y_n\in \bar A \ : n\in \mathbb N\}$$

is not finite (If it is finite $\{y_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence). By definition, there is $x_{m_1}$ such that $d(y_1, x_{m_1}) \leq \epsilon/2$. Write $k_1 = 1$. Assume by induction that

$$k_1< k_2 <\cdots < k_n\ ,\  m_1 < m_2 < \cdots <m_n$$

has been chosen such that $d(y_{k_l} ,x_{m_l}) \leq 1 / 2^l$ for $l = 1, \cdots, n$. Then consider the set

$$\{y_a:\ \ a> k_n\}\ .$$

This set is not finite by assumption, thus there is $k_{n+1} > k_n$ such that

$$y_{k_{n+1}}\notin \{ x_i:\ \ \ 1\leq i\leq m_n\}\ .$$

Thus there is $m_{n+1} > m_n$ such that $d(y_{k_{n+1}} ,  x_{m_{n+1}}) \leq 1/2^{n+1}$. Thus by induction we have found subsequences $\{y_{k_n}\}$ of $\{y_n\}$ and $\{x_{m_n}\}$ of $\{x_n\}$ such that $d(y_{k_n}, x_{m_n}) \leq 1 / 2^n$.

By your assumption, by again picking a subsequence if necessary, $\{x_{m_n}\}$ converges to some $x\in \bar A$. Then for all $\epsilon >0$ there is $N\in \mathbb N$ such that

$$d(x, x_{m_n}) <\epsilon,\ \ \ \forall n\geq N\ .$$

Pick a large $N$ such that $1/2^N\leq \epsilon$, then

$$d(y_{k_n} , x) \leq d(y_{k_n}, x_{m_n}) + d(x_{m_n}, x) < 2\epsilon,\ \ \forall n \geq N\ .$$

Which means that $\{y_{k_n}\}$ converges to $x$. Thus $\bar A$ is sequentially compact.

Comment: Excellent answer, @John! Thank you very much! Just one remark: It's not necessarily true that $(x_{m_n})_{n\in\mathbb Z_+}$ converges, but then we can just pick a subsequence $(x_{m_{n_{\ell}}})_{\ell\in\mathbb Z_+}$ that does (my assumption guarantees only this) and work with this sub-subsequence and the associated $(y_{k_{n_{\ell}}})_{\ell\in\mathbb Z_+}$ from then on.

Comment: @triple_sec: Thanks, I overlooked that. ^^